# Search for Value and Return All Columns In Which Value Appears

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have the following set of lists of names in a Google Sheet:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║   ║     A      ║     B    ║     C    ║
╠═══╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 1 ║ Barry      ║ Rich     ║ David    ║
╠═══╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 2 ║ Rich       ║ Jeff     ║ Michael  ║
╠═══╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 3 ║ Bruce      ║ Bruce    ║ Jeff     ║
╠═══╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 4 ║ Rober      ║ Barry    ║ Joel     ║
╠═══╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 5 ║ David      ║ Joel     ║ Howard   ║
╠═══╬════════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 6 ║ Michael    ║ Howard   ║ Rich     ║
╚═══╩════════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

I'm trying to figure out a formula to use that searches for a name and returns all the names that appear in each column the name appears in. For example, if I search for Joel I want to get the entire contents of columns B and C.

Comment: Please also check the [latest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64871181/1527780)  as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for a formula that

> ...searches for a name and returns all the names that appear in each column the name appears in

Please use the following formula

```
=query(ArrayFormula(regexextract( 
                query(flatten(TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(column(A2:C)&"-"&A2:C))), 
                   "where Col1 matches '"&textjoin("|",1,(ArrayFormula(if(A2:C=A1,column(A2:C)&"-.*",""))))&"' ") 
                                ,"-(.*)")),  
    "where Col1 is not null ")
```

[image: Return each column in whole where A1 is present]

Comment: This is great. It does the same thing as the solution offered by @kirkg13 but with less code.

Comment: *" It does the same thing as... "*. Kind of. **The great benefit of the above formula is that it remains the same regardless how long the list of names is**, while in the other formula you need to update it and expand the "loop" for every single row added. Can you imagine the length of it if you have e.g. 20 or 50 rows? I would say that the closest formula is the one by @basic

Comment: Yeah. As the spreadsheet grows, more columns will be added. I have a custom function that uses getLastColumn() to set that in this formula (I substituted it in all the places where your sample refers to column C and it works well). This way I don't have to make constant adjustments as it grows.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$C,0,SMALL(FILTER(FLATTEN(COLUMN($A:$C)*("Jeff"=$A:$C)),FLATTEN(COLUMN($A:$C)*("Jeff"=$A:$C))>0),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

This formula autofill rows, but not columns, so copy it to the right.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=VLOOKUP("Joel", A:C, {2, 3}, 0)
```

next level:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1, Sheet1:A:C, {2, 3}, 0))
```

next level:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, Sheet1:A:C, {2, 3}, 0)))
```

if more columns:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, Sheet1:A:C, COLUMN(B:K), 0)))
```

if Joel is in B column and you want to return A and C column:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A, {Sheet1!B:B, Sheet1!A:C}, {2, 4}, 0)))
```

Comment: These are only returning one name each for me. I need to get the entire column that "Joel" appears in.

Comment: @Dave can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: It's proprietary so I can't share it but it's exactly the same as my above sample but with many more rows and columns.

Comment: its not rly clear whats your input... your joel is in one cell or across range? if its in one cell  you expect output to be multiple rows? row 4 and row 5 from your example ?

Comment: "Joel" is in B5 and C4. So I'd want a list of all the names in columns B and C. Using the same sample data, if I searched on "Michael" (which is in A6 and C2) I'd want a list of names in columns A and C.

Comment: @Dave I see. in that case use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64865489/5632629

Answer (score 0):

or maybe:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(A:A&" "&B:B&" "&C:C, 
 REGEXMATCH(A:A&" "&B:B&" "&C:C, D10)), D10, )), " ")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an output like this:
[image]

Let us know if this helps or not.

The main formula is a bit brute force, but pretty straightforward.
But it might have issues depending on how many rows or columns you might have in your data.

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(A1:C6)},"
             where Col1 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col2 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col3 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col4 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col5 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col6 = '" & F1 & "' ",0))
```

**UPDATE:**

To put all of the results into a single column, there are several options.  You haven't said if you want unique values, or the names sorted, so I'll ignore those aspects, and just stack the results vertically.

One simple way is the use of an undocumented function, `FLATTEN`, which may be or may not be removed from Sheets at some point.

Added to my original formula, that gives:

```
=FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(A1:C6)},"
             where Col1 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col2 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col3 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col4 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col5 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col6 = '" & F1 & "' ",0)))
```

But you may want one column stacked on top of another, not a merger of them.  In that case, you could try this ugly formula, which needss to repeat the query multiple times, to check how many columns there are in the output.  If you have to go this way, I recommend to either save the query results in a helper range, or perhaps submit a new more specific question:

```
={query({TRANSPOSE(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(A1:C6)},"
             where Col1 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col2 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col3 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col4 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col5 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col6 = '" & F1 & "' ",0))},"select Col1 ",0); 
 if(columns(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(A1:C6)},"
             where Col1 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col2 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col3 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col4 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col5 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col6 = '" & F1 & "' ",0)))>1,
     query({TRANSPOSE(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(A1:C6)},"
             where Col1 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col2 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col3 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col4 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col5 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col6 = '" & F1 & "' ",0))},"select Col2 ",0),
     "");
  if(columns(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(A1:C6)},"
             where Col1 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col2 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col3 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col4 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col5 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col6 = '" & F1 & "' ",0)))>2,
     query({TRANSPOSE(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(A1:C6)},"
             where Col1 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col2 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col3 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col4 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col5 = '" & F1 & "' 
                or Col6 = '" & F1 & "' ",0))},"select Col3 ",0),
     "")}
```

[image]

Comment: This is working well for me but what if I wanted all the data to display in one column?

Comment: Please add your comments back into your question, to make it clearer for others in the future, as they read questions to see if they match their situation.  There are several ways of putting the results sinto one column.  See my edited answer above.

Comment: Depending on your data, I now realise my formula might well need some enhancements, to count the number of rows of input data, and modify the query accordingly.  I'll wait to hear if this is an issue for you, before proceeding.

Comment: I do want UNIQUE and SORT. Using the FLATTEN solution I can very easily wrap the whole thing in UNIQUE and SORT (formulas I use often). In your opinion, is this the best way?